# How can i do a join between two table and do a filter in the same way?

Tags: powerapps

I am trying to do a left join between two tables in powerapps for returning an id, a family name and a last name but I want to do like a "where" in SQL.

I am trying some things but it doesn't give me all the records I have to return.

I tried this:

```
ClearCollect(
    collecIdSalaries;
    Filter(
        team ;
        id_affaire = inpRechercheChantier.Text
    )
);;
ClearCollect(
    collecIdSalaries;
    Filter(
        collecIdSalaries;
        (DateDiff(
            Today();
            dt_fin
        ) > 0) Or (DateDiff(
            dt_debut;
            Today()
        ) > 0)
    )
);;

ClearCollect(
    collecNomSalaries;
    Filter(
        salarie;
       id_salarie in collecIdSalaries.id_intervenant
    )
);;
```

It's supposed to return 15 id but it returns me 4 and a message about the "in", problem with delegation